# Where can I download the flight plan data around the world?

Tags: flight-planning, website, datasets

Where can I download the flight plan data around the world, so that I have analyze their route?

Are they provided freely?

Comment: Related: [Is there a Flights API to get flight information months in advance?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7959/1289) and [How can I get flight destination from ADS-B?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7986/1289)

Comment: Thanks. For flight plan data (not ADS-B data), is it monopolized by some companies but not publicly available?

Comment: The flight plan, as a list of waypoints etc, is proprietary information of the airlines or private pilots producing those plans. It is provided to the national and international authorities / flight services but I don't know if any of these organisations have any need to share them with the public. Obviously, in normal circumstances, travel agents and passengers only want to know the departure and arrival times and locations. Flight plans are also subject to change, for example to avoid weather.

Answer (score 2):

For historical FAA IFR flight plan data, you can get it from www.flightaware.com.  They show five minute delayed, and with a free registered account you can get access to the last 90 days worth of data.  You can pay for data older than that and I believe in different data formats.

I'm not aware of a similar source for other parts of the world.